# Filtering NSMutableArray of NSDictionary with NSPredicate

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary, nspredicate

I'm having an NSObject entity for storing some data like name, id from server

NSObject file looks like below,

```
@interface MyEntity : NSObject
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSString *userId;
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSString *userName;
- (id)initWithJSON:(NSDictionary *)dataDict;
@end

- (id)initWithJSON:(NSDictionary *)dataDict
{
   if (self = [super init])
   {
       self.userId = [dataDict objectForKeyNotNull:@"userId"] ;
       self.userName = [dataDict objectForKeyNotNull:@"userName"] ;
   }
   return self;
}
```

I'm storing the values from server to an NSMutableArray by,

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:responseData[@"result"]];
for (NSDictionary *dict in array) {
        MyEntity *ent = [[MyEntity alloc] initWithJSON:dict];
        [myArray addObject:ent];
}
```

Now, I want to filter that NSMutableArray by some usernames using NSPredicate. I've tried below code,

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY MyEntity.userName == %@", @"popo"];
NSArray *predicateFilteredArray = [myArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
[myArray removeAllObjects];
[myArray addObjectsFromArray:predicateFilteredArray];
```

it's not working. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just do not need to check predicate with its entity name write simple predicate and it will work I mean replace your code

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY MyEntity.userName == %@", @"popo"];
```

With

`NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"userName == %@", @"popo"];` and it will work.

Comment: I believe it should be SELF.userName LIKE OR MATCH. you are comparing NSStrings, you can't use equality check in NSString

Comment: `"userName == %@"` should work, I don't think that you have to add "SELF". And you *can* compare strings for equality in a predicate.

Comment: @MartinR, It's working great for username == . I also needs to filter with userId which is greater than some integer value. How can I do that? Pl assist.

Comment: @NAZIK: The ["Predicate Programming Guide"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/AdditionalChapters/Introduction.html) explains the syntax and has lots of examples ...

Comment: @NAZIK if user id is integer then use Use [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"userName == %@ && userId > %d", @"popo",10];

Comment: `userId > %d` is not working, `-[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb0000000000000a2` error occured. Should I change the datatype of userid to integer. Is there anyother way?

Comment: @NAZIK yes this exception occurs only when your userId is not an integer and you are using comparator operator of integer (> or <).

Comment: To verify it if you should replace your > operator with == operator and the exception will disappear although the result will not right, because == operator can work for both string and integer.